# Access user group history (see what groups I was in before I ran usermod without the -a flag)

Tags: xubuntu, users, groups

Running Xubuntu 16.04

Made a newbie mistake; while I was adding my own account to the 'wireshark' group so I can start wireshark without using `sudo`, I've removed myself from all the other groups I was in, including `sudo`.

I used this command:

```
sudo usermod -G wireshark my_user_account
```

I'm thinking I forgot the `-a` before the `-G`?

Does anyone know how to view the history of a user as it relates to group membership. Or view a group history as it relates to user membership?

Just trying to get my user back into the groups it was in before I had a brainfart.

Answer (score 1):

I booted into single-user mode by editing Grub to:

1. make the filesystem `rw` instead of `ro`, and
2. adding `init=/bin/bash` at the end of the line.

After that I was able to add myself back into the `sudo` group using:

```
usermod -aG sudo my_user_account
```

I then rebooted back into "normal" mode. Ran `sudo grep group /var/log/auth.log` and was able to see the command I ran that removed me from my groups, and it listed the groups I was removed from.

I went through each of them again doing `sudo usermod -aG _group_ my_user_account`.

Once I did that, I logged out and logged back in and everything seems to be back to normal. Hope this helps someone else who made the same mistake I did.

You'd think after 16 years of using Linux, I wouldn't make boneheaded mistakes like this, but apparently not...

Comment: That's why commands like `adduser` exist. `adduser user group` is far more convenient and safer than `usermod -aG`.